# Typeorm: how to model an entity type that can have different sets of attributes?

Tags: typeorm

trying to find a solution for how to deal with typeorm in case you have entities with different types.

The example is vividly described in this article https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/149904/how-to-model-an-entity-type-that-can-have-different-sets-of-attributes. I am trying to achieve the same functionality using typeorm.
Goals of this approach

1. Items have shared ids
2. DB strcuture is self representative
3. All items can be fetched in one query

In typeorm dosc there is information about enitity inheritance https://typeorm.io/#/entity-inheritance

Using concrete table inheritance entities will have not shared ids (id incremental one) and reference to category is not that clear, and DB diagram is not so self explaining, you dont see the shared part, its obvious only in code (you see can entities extends each other). All entities can not be fetched in one query (except we using union)

Using single table inheritance we have the same issue with the diagram, id problem is solved, but our table has a lot of null values and consumes more memory. We cant fetch all entities in one query without query builder and getRawMany

Tried to implement structure from the article using Typeorm

```
@Entity('items')
export class ItemEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id!: string;

  @Column()
  name!: string;

  @Column()
  icon!: string;

  @Column()
  stackAmount!: string;

  @Column()
  buyPrice!: number;

  @Column()
  sellPrice!: number;
}

@Entity('equipments')
export class EquipmentEntity {
  @OneToOne((type) => ItemEntity, { primary: true })
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'itemId' })
  itemId!: ItemEntity;

  @Column()
  quality!: number; //enum

  @Column()
  equipmentLevel!: number;

  @Column()
  requiredLevel!: number;
}

@Entity('armour')
export class ArmourEntity {
  @OneToOne((type) => EquipmentEntity, { primary: true })
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'equipmentId' })
  equipmentId!: EquipmentEntity;

  @Column()
  blockRating!: number;
}

@Entity('weapons')
export class WeaponEntity {
  @OneToOne((type) => EquipmentEntity, { primary: true })
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'equipmentId' })
  equipmentId!: EquipmentEntity;

  @Column()
  damageMin!: number;

  @Column()
  weaponDelay!: number;

  @Column()
  damageMax!: number;

  damageType!: number; 
}

@Entity('trade_goods')
export class TradeGoodsEntity {
  @OneToOne((type) => ItemEntity, { primary: true })
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'itemId' })
  itemId!: ItemEntity;

  @Column()
  tradable!: number;
}
```

Its how it looks like [DB diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aqld6.png)

In my case the most common read operation is to get all items (weapons/amour/trade_goods)

To fetch all items in one query (with joined tables), I used queryBuilder with getRawMany(), otherwise, if I am using getMany it removes properties that are not in Item Entity

But this approach has several disadvantages, class Weapon does not extend Equipment and Item, otherwise, the table will be populated with these columns, and we idea to avoid this. So Entity doesn't have fields it should have. The second, query builder should be called with getRawMany...

I'm sure its quite popular case, and here should be a solution, could someone share a link to docs or guide how to deal with such structure using typeorm?